# How to join same table to check if a>b with 10

Tags: mysql, join, compare

Table ***mytable***

```
id      numbers       whereonly

1       2                1
2       35               1
3       22               1
4       20               1
5       3                1
6       70               1
7       80.15925         1
8       60               7
9       50               7
```

I need to order by **numbers** and to take id 1 to search until I found an id that have **numbers** row bigger with 10.

**Desired result: 2, 20, 35, 70, 80.15925**

Only where column **whereonly** is 1

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: 2, 20, 35, 70, 80.15925

Comment: I don't think the data set is properly representative of the problem. For instance, this answer produces the correct result, but I can't say definitively that it's right: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa080/9

Comment: True, but when I apply whereonly=1 dont work

Comment: 'Don't work' is not an acceptable expression in SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id AS id, t1.numbers AS numbers
FROM table AS t1
INNER JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.numbers > t2.numbers - 10
WHERE t1.whereonly = 1
GROUP BY t2.numbers
ORDER BY t1.numbers;
```

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05cce/3).

> Edit 1: As [strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry) suggested

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
  FROM mytable x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT t2.numbers t2n
            , MIN(t1.id) id
         FROM mytable t1
         JOIN mytable t2 
           ON t1.numbers > t2.numbers - 10
        GROUP 
           BY t2.numbers
     ) y
    ON y.id = x.id
    ORDER BY x.numbers
    WHERE x.whereonly = 1;
```

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05cce/2).

Comment: If you find that you've got DISTINCT and GROUP BY in the same query then something's probably gone wrong. Equally if you find yourself with a GROUP BY clause but no aggregating functions then, again, something's (almost) certainly not right.

Comment: @Strawberry Nice tip. But this also produces correct result.

Comment: How to add ORDER BY numbers ASC?

Comment: So does SELECT 2 numbers UNION SELECT 20, etc. That's proof of nothing.

Comment: That said, I believe you could rewrite your query as follows and it *would* be a candidate solution http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65a35/15

Comment: 2, 20, 35, 70, 80.15925 Expected output in new case?

Comment: Yes, same result 2, 20, 35, 70, 80.15925

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be704/1 with the update the result is 2,35,70,80.15925. Number 20 is not there.